# What is the difference between declaring an object outside and inside of a loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, memory

I was wondering, what is the difference if any between these two ways of using an object obj. And what will happen to the memory in both examples?

- Example 1: Object is declared outside of the loop
- Example 2: Object is declared inside of the loop.
- In both example I call function **func** which takes as parameters a `vector` of type `float`. The dimension of this vector is no less than **9000** elements.

---

## Example 1

```
MyObject obj;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
{
    obj.func(vector<float>);
}
```

---

## Example 2

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
{
    MyObject obj;
    obj.func(vector<float>);
}
```

---

Comment: You might want to learn about [scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)

Comment: @HaniGoc , if you leave comments like that, the question will just get more down-votes.

Comment: He has a point though.  It was a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you declare the object inside the loop, a new object will be created on each iteration and the exising one destroyed at the end of each iteration. This is because the object will have a scope inside the `{}`.

When you declare it outside, a single object is created and you work with that, But when you put it inside a loop, a new object is created and destroyed on each iteration, which will affect the speed.

That is, when you use

```
MyObject obj;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
{
    obj.func(vector<float>);
}
```

you crate only one object. But when you use

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
{
    MyObject obj;
    obj.func(vector<float>);
}
```

you create and destroy `n` objects. That will increase the execution time. So, it's better to use the first.

Comment: When the loop ends, or when a iteration ends?

Comment: and So it's better for the memory?

Comment: Actually you create a new MyObject for each iteration.   Put a print in the constructor and try it.

Comment: No, when each iteration ends. Then it's reconstructed for the next iteration. It will reuse the memory, but there might be an impact if creating and destroying it takes time. And of course the behaviour might be different if the function modifies the object's state.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I am asking this question because after a given time the for loop is getting slower. So i was wondering if using an object inside and outside of the loop has a difference

Comment: @MikeSeymour , yup. My mistake. Edited

Comment: @MikeSeymour , is it correct now ? or is there something else I should add